# Enter Unicode characters with 8-digit hex code

Tags: vim, unicode, utf-16, utf

How do I enter Unicode characters like  without copying it to the clipboard and pasting it?

Things I know:

- The command `ga` on the character  gives me `hex:0001d4ed`.
- I can copy it on the clipboard and paste it via `"+p`.
- I know how to enter Unicode values that have a 4 digit hex code:
  `<C-v>u` for example `<C-v>u03b1` gives the `α` character.

Comment: There are no unicode codepoints that require 8 hex digits.  6 is the maximum as `0x10ffff` is the maximum codepoint.

Comment: +1 for the "ga" command!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `<C-v>U`, that is, an uppercase u, to input an 8 digit hex codepoint character.

More information [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters).

Comment: you're so fast - I can't accept it yet. ;-) thank you - I completely overread the `<C-v>U` in the first link you gave me, when I read it first.

Answer (score 13):

There is a Vim feature designed to simplify entering characters that
cannot be typed directly. It is called Digraphs (see `:help digraphs`).

To define a custom digraph for entering ‘’, use an Ex command similar
to the one below.

```
:dig dd 120045
```

where `120045` is the decimal representation of ‘’, as one can easily
confirm using the `ga` command.

Inserting a character using a digraph is simple:
Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by the shortcut of that
digraph (`dd` for the above example).

Comment: defining a global digraph - sounds a bit overkill to me I only have to insert the character once or twice and then  have a `imap <buffer> \curld ` in a tex-plugin to use it just with latex - in other places I don't need it and digraphs I can enter via the keyboard-compose key (I use the neo-keyboard-layout).

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Yeah, that is a fine approach, too.

Answer (score 6):

There exists a [Unicode plugin for Vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim). According to the [plugin description](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2822), this plugin has three main features:

1. Character/digraph completion using either the Unicode name or the codepoint.
2. Identify the character/digraph under the cursor.
3. Search for digraphs by name; transform two normal characters into their corresponding digraph.